# Spring Security 4 with custom provider and handlers not caching the url before authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've configured a custom authentication provider, a success handler and a failure handler in Spring Security (v4.0.1). When using the default ones, after displaying the login page, the user was redirected to the previously requested url. However, I lost that behaviour when implementing my own ones, so I'm trying to recover it.

Basically, right now, I'm being redirected to the home page everytime I log in, even I've accesed the login page trying to fetch another resource (in my case */web/users*). That's the configuration I have right now:

@Configuration bean (extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/web/logout"))
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/web/login");

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/web/recovery").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/web/users").authenticated().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .failureHandler(failureHandler).loginPage("/web/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/web/j_spring_security_check")
            .successHandler(successHandler).permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
        DataSource ds, PasswordEncoder pwdEncoder) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}
```

The custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
public class SystemAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private IUserService service;

public SystemAuthenticationSuccessHandler(IUserService service) {
    this.service = service;
    setDefaultTargetUrl("/web/home");
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    User user = service.findByIdOrEmail(username, username);
    if (user != null) {
        service.saveLoginSuccess(user.getId());
    }
    //Call the parent method to manage the successful authentication
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

Basically, the problem I have is `requestCache` is always returning `null` for current request in the [`SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler#onAuthenticationSuccess`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html#onAuthenticationSuccess%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%29) method and that's because the [`HttpSessionRequestCache#saveRequest`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/HttpSessionRequestCache.html#saveRequest%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method doesn't match my incoming request before being redirected to the login page.

Specifically, the `HttpSessionRequestCache` Spring is using is an [`AndRequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AndRequestMatcher.html) which discards all my incoming requests. I want it to use the [`AnyRequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/AnyRequestMatcher.html), but don't know how to tell Spring that.

**Update**

Having set a breakpoint in `HttpSessionRequestCache#setRequestMatcher`, that's the concrete point where Spring Security sets it:

[image]

However, I don't know how to set a custom request cache configurer for my case! Isn't there an easier way for doing it?

**Update 2**

I've discovered right now this issue only happens when using Firefox and not with Chrome or Internet Explorer.

Comment: If the only thing you do in your succes listener is log something you are better of using an `ApplicationListener` and listen for `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`s and do the logging there.

Comment: @M.Deinum even if I change my own success handler for a default success url in the configuration, my problem keeps happening.

Comment: You shouldn't need either....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a problem with my current firefox browser. Even if I remove all the navigation and cache data, it keeps happening, but not with other browsers as Chrome or IE, not even with other FF browsers.